# Angular 4 - Access HTML elements in Typescript using FormControlName

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to access HTML elements in typescript using FormcontrolName.

I can able to access `html` element using ID of elements

For example :

```
var element = document.getElementById("txtID")
```

But can we access the element using FormControl (without use of ID)

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use QuerySelector of HTML5.

If your html input tag is like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtID" formControlName="txtID" />
var element = document.querySelector("input[formControlName='txtID']");
```

Comment: Here you have mention selector name . but i don't want to mention it.                                 is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can remove id attribute

Comment: var element = document.querySelector("[formControlName='txtID']"); this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

[Try Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckjfa2)

HTML :

```
<h2>Using [formControl]</h2>
<input type="text" [formControl]="myControl"> {{ myControl.value }}
<button (click)="focusToFormControl()">Focus</button>

<hr>

<h2>Using formControlName</h2>
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="foo">
    <button (click)="focusToFormControlName('foo')">Focus</button>
</form>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl,FormControlDirective, FormControlName, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


const originFormControlNgOnChanges = FormControlDirective.prototype.ngOnChanges;
FormControlDirective.prototype.ngOnChanges = function () {
  this.form.nativeElement = this.valueAccessor._elementRef.nativeElement;
  return originFormControlNgOnChanges.apply(this, arguments);
};

const originFormControlNameNgOnChanges = FormControlName.prototype.ngOnChanges;
FormControlName.prototype.ngOnChanges = function () {
  const result = originFormControlNameNgOnChanges.apply(this, arguments);
  this.control.nativeElement = this.valueAccessor._elementRef.nativeElement;
  return result;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  myControl = new FormControl();

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      foo: ''
    });
  }

  focusToFormControl() {
    (<any>this.myControl).nativeElement.focus();


  }

  focusToFormControlName(name) {
    (<any>this.myForm.get(name)).nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply.  Code is not working . Is it neecessary to use focus while using nativeelement

Comment: sorry for inconvenience  please refer update code i have give wrong  url by mistake.